# New Swift app Lister error: "No matching provisioning profiles found", "App ID with Identifier ... is not available"

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, ios-provisioning, xcode6-beta6

I downloaded the sample code for the Lister app from Apple's developer website and am trying to build the Swift version to my iPhone 5S running iOS 8 Beta 5. I've changed everything to com.mycompany.Lister, but when I try to build it, it comes up with the following error.

**No matching provisioning profiles found**

None of the valid provisioning profiles allowed the specified entitlements: com.apple.developer.ubiquity-container-identifiers. Xcode can resolve this issue by downloading a new provisioning profile from the Member Center.

So I click "Fix Issue", it loads for a few seconds and comes back to me with this message:

An App ID with Identifier 'com.example.apple-samplecode.Lister.ListerToday' is not available. Please enter a different string.

I thought I had already changed everything to com.mycompany.Lister, but maybe I'm missing something hidden somewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Build Settings change the Code Signing Identities from Distribution to Developer or don't code sign.

As per @markerberg's comment: The trick is to go through the compile settings for all 8 items (toggle via drop down in the upper left corner of build settings). For each of the targets you need to change all the code signing options to "don't code sign". Then it works right away.

Comment: The trick is to go through the compile settings for all 8 items (toggle via drop down in the upper left corner of build settings). For each of targets you need to change all the code signing options to "don't code sign". Then it works right away.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by creating an "App Store" distribution provisioning profile for my App on the developer.apple.com provisioning portal. The reasoning is outlined here. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1830/_index.html

I am fairly sure that Xcode did this for me automatically last time I created an objective-C app, but this is my first Swift app and somehow it seems i had to do it manually even though I was just submitting for beta testing via TestFlight.

Answer (score 0):

I was following instructions mentioned in the ReadMe file provided with the source code (It is called iOS and Watch Quick Start). But while using Xcode's 'Fix Issue' option for creating Provisioning Profiles, I was getting the error mentioned above.

I had to quit and restart Xcode to solve this issue. After restarting Xcode, Fix Issue option seemed to be working for me.